# Mixing two layout managers inside the same window in Python (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am pretty new to Python and Tkinter, so I hope this question will be easy for the seniors...

I have this checkerboard:

[image]

I am using a grid layout management, as can be noticed below:

```
from tkinter import *

def checkerboard(can):
    w = can.winfo_width()
    h = can.winfo_height()
    cellwidth = w / 4
    cellheight = h / 4

    for row in range(4):
        for col in range(4):
            x1=col * cellwidth
            y1=row * cellheight
            x2=(col + 1) * cellwidth
            y2=(row + 1) * cellheight
            can.create_rectangle(col * cellwidth, row * cellheight, (col + 1) * cellwidth, (row + 1) * cellheight,
                                 fill='white')
            can.create_text(((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2),text='A')

window = Tk()
thecanvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)
thecanvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
window.update_idletasks()
checkerboard(thecanvas)
window.mainloop()
```

The problem is that I want to add a previous line over the checkerboard, which does not belong to the grid layout. Something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would probably just remove the top border of the checkboard or set its color to white (I don't remember exactly the tkinter options at the moment).

Comment: Any reason you're forbidden to put your checkboard in a frame?

Comment: Do the lines have to be a part of Canvas?

Comment: you don't use grid manager to create checkboard but you use canvas - and it makes different. You can use create_text to add text to canvas. or you can put Label in row=0 and canvas in row=1, or you can use pack instead of grid.

Comment: Please fix your indentation, or at the very least verify that the above code supposed to be running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use `grid` to create checkoard, you use `grid` only to put canvas in window.

`Canvas` is in `row=0` so you can put it in `row=2` and then you can put `Labels` in `row=0` and `row=1`

```
l1 = Label(window, text="I WANT TO CREATE THIS LABEL")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

l2 = Label(window, text="AND THIS TOO", fg='red')
l2.grid(row=1, column=0)

thecanvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)
thecanvas.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Full code

```
from tkinter import *

def checkerboard(can):
    w = can.winfo_width()
    h = can.winfo_height()
    cellwidth = w / 4
    cellheight = h / 4

    for row in range(4):
        for col in range(4):
            x1=col * cellwidth
            y1=row * cellheight
            x2=(col + 1) * cellwidth
            y2=(row + 1) * cellheight
            can.create_rectangle(col * cellwidth, row * cellheight, (col + 1) * cellwidth, (row + 1) * cellheight,
                                     fill='white')
            can.create_text(((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2),text='A')

window = Tk()

l1 = Label(window, text="I WANT TO CREATE THIS LABEL")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

l2 = Label(window, text="AND THIS TOO", fg='red')
l2.grid(row=1, column=0)

thecanvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)
thecanvas.grid(row=2, column=0)

window.update_idletasks()
checkerboard(thecanvas)
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Instead of `grid()` you can even use `pack()` and you get the same result

```
l1 = Label(window, text="I WANT TO CREATE THIS LABEL")
l1.pack()

l2 = Label(window, text="AND THIS TOO", fg='red')
l2.pack()

thecanvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)
thecanvas.pack()
```

If you really need to mix managers then you can also put `Frame` in `row=0` and `Canvas` in `row=1` and then you can use `pack()` inside `Frame`

```
frame = Frame(window)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

l1 = Label(frame, text="I WANT TO CREATE THIS LABEL")
l1.pack()

l2 = Label(frame, text="AND THIS TOO", fg='red')
l2.pack()

thecanvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)
thecanvas.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Comment: Just one more thing... How can I align the labels to the left? Just like the picture that I displayed before

Comment: grid and pack use different arguments to align - see [example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/align-grid-pack)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to create a frame for the checkerboard, and then you can create the widgets in that frame. In the main window, you can use any geometry manager you want to add the checkerboard and any other widgets.

Though, in this specific case you can just move the canvas to row one and add anything else in row 0.